# Add_Index() Error using Rails ,PostGres and Windows xp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-xp

I'm trying to add an index to my models, but keep getting this error.

> PG:Error Error:column "user_id" does
>   not exist :CREATE INDEX
>   "index_users_on_user_id" ON "users"
>   ("user_id")

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.references :role
      t.references :carrier
      t.string "first_name"
      t.string "last_name"
      t.string "user_name"
      t.string "hashed_password"
      t.string "user_salt"
      t.string "telephone"

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index("users", "user_id")
    add_index("users", "role_id")
    add_index("users", "user_name")
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have anywhere the column user_id in the migration. The automagical column that rails creates for you is called 'id'.

Comment: so it would be add_index("users", "id")?

Comment: in fact this column will be the primary key, postgresql will create index for that, no need of another one.